# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'brand')

Tags: javascript, html

While creating this short script I came across this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'brand'). Below is the code that I wrote. Its says error is on the line <p class="brand">${bikes[i].brand}</p>

```
const bikes = [
  {
    brand: "Specialized",
    name: `Specialized STUMPJUMPER EVO - 29" Carbon Mountainbike - cast battleship`,
    price: "5.461,34 €",
    image: "../img/mtb/Stumpjumper.jpg",
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i <= bikes.length; i++) {
  let bikeElement = `
<div class="card">
  <p class="brand">${bikes[i].brand}</p>
</div>`;
  createBikes();
  function createBikes() {
    document
      .getElementById("container")
      .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", bikeElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try ; i < bikes.length instead of ; i <= bikes.length in your for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch your `for` loop to use `<` instead of `<=`. The length of your array is `1`. If `i == 1`, it will be unable to find the `array[1]` item, since arrays are indexed starting with `0`.

```js
const bikes = [
  {
    brand: "Specialized",
    name: `Specialized STUMPJUMPER EVO - 29" Carbon Mountainbike - cast battleship`,
    price: "5.461,34 €",
    image: "../img/mtb/Stumpjumper.jpg",
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < bikes.length; i++) {
  let bikeElement = `
<div class="card">
  <p class="brand">${bikes[i].brand}</p>
</div>`;
  createBikes();
  function createBikes() {
    document
      .getElementById("container")
      .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", bikeElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```